# Error while insering-not all variables bound

Tags: c#, oracle

When I run the below code "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" is showing. Wile debugging I could see value of @Number in this statement-> "ParameterDirection.Input, @NUMBER" .But while executing error is showing.

```
     DB_Common _dbCommon = new DB_Common();
                DbConnection conn2 = _dataFactory.CreateConnection();
                DbCommand cmd1 = _dataFactory.CreateCommand();
                conn2.ConnectionString = ABC.AppSettings ["ORACnnStr_HOSPITAL"];
                conn2.Open();

        cmd1.Connection = conn2;
                cmd1.Transaction = trans;
                cmd1.CommandText = OracleHelper.FixCommandText("INSERT INTO NBTABLE(NUMBER) VALUES(@NUMBER) ");

   cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DbParameter param2 = null;
                foreach (DataRow dr2 in _DTF_SPE.Rows)
                {
                    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

                    OracleHelper.CreateParameter(ref cmd, ref param, "@NUMBER", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, @NUMBER);

                 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
    }
            }

            trans.Commit();
        }
```

EDIT

Updated the code as below.The value of @doctor is taking from conn1.conn1 is closed before starting conn2. ORA-01008: not all variables bound is showing while executing.

```
        DB_Common _dbCommon = new DB_Common();
            DbConnection conn2 = _dataFactory.CreateConnection();
            DbCommand cmd1 = _dataFactory.CreateCommand();
            conn2.ConnectionString = SCC.AppSettings["ORACnnStr_abc"];
            conn2.Open();
            cmd1.Connection = conn2;
            cmd1.Transaction = trans;
            cmd1.CommandText = OracleHelper.FixCommandText("INSERT INTO numbertable(Doctor,PART,CODE) VALUES(@doctor,'K','G') ");

            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DbParameter param2 = null;

            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.Dispose();
```

Comment: of course `INSERT INTO NBTABLE(NUMBER) VALUES('123')` succeeds. Since, the problem stems from `@NUMBER`(assignment with @ sign)

Answer (score 0):

Use semicolon `:` format instead of `@` format for 
`"INSERT INTO NBTABLE(NUMBER) VALUES(:NUMBER_) "` and you had better to give a name(like `NUMBER_`) other than `NUMBER`(keyword).

And call without `@` again : 
`OracleHelper.CreateParameter(ref cmd, ref param, "NUMBER_",....`